# Magnetic Field Simulation Software for Particle Physics

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields, simulations, software

I have been trying to use software for modelling a system of magnetic field, but regrettably they do not make the cut. Is there any software that allows the input of specific requirements into a magnetic system, with data inputs in 3D space such as the SI unit distance between objects, electric charge, mass, volume and magnetic properties?

Comment: What do electric charge and mass have to do with calculating magnetic fields? Are trying to find fields generated by moving charges? It will probably be necessary to give more details to get a useful response. Do you have soft ferromagnetic materials in the system? Are they near saturation? Is hysteresis important? Do you have hard ferromagnets? Are there currents, fixed or variable? Is this a statics problem or is dynamics important?

Comment: As the question states, this is related somewhat to particle physics, as it involves accelerating metallic ions. As such, the charge and mass of the ion is important. It is a dynamic system, and is quite variable, so it will involve soft ferromagnetic systems, diamagnetic materials amongst other requirements, that is why I’d appreciate if there was a program that let you input values, and not a materials selection